# Smooth function on a closed set.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evans book on PDE's defines for a given open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,

$C^{k}(\overline{U})=\lbrace u:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that $D^{\alpha}u$ exists and is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $U$, for all mulitindexes $\alpha$, with $|\alpha|\leq k\rbrace$

Alternatively one could define,

$C^{k}(\overline{U})=\lbrace u:\overline{U}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n},$ such that there exists an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ containing $\overline{U}$, and an extension of $u$ to $V$ that has continous partial derivatives up to order $k$ in $V\rbrace$

Are this definitions equivalent? Is this trivial?

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe we need $\partial U$ to be smooth enough.

Comment: (first definition just says that the derivatives can be continously extended to $\overline{U}$)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about Whitney's extension theorem. Am I correct in assuming this is a direct consequence of it? Are there any conditions to be imposed on $\partial U$?